# Uploading files with tomahawk - problem with displaying error message

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I'm uploading files with `<t:inputFileUpload`all is working fine but when file is larger from value set in web.xml it doesn't  output any error or warning message.
My code:

```
  <h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
               <t:inputFileUpload id="fileupload" accept="image/*" storage="file"
                    value="#{fileUpload.uploadedFile}" styleClass="fileUploadInput"
                    required="true" validator="epacient.FileUploadValidator"  validatorMessage="Napacna vrsta ali prevelika datoteka."/>
                <h:message for="fileupload" style="color: red;" />
                <br />
                <h:commandButton value="Upload" id="fileUploadButton" action="#{fileUpload.upload}" />
                <h:message for="uploadForm" style="color: red;" />
   </h:form>
```

If file is to big it should write an error at `<h:message` tag, am I wrong?

How can I resolve the problem ?

best regards

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with Tomahawk. You can however configure the `uploadMaxFileSize` in the [`ExtensionsFilter`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html), but when it occurs, it will hard-throw a [`SizeLimitExceededException`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException.html) which goes beyond all the JSF thing so that the enduser ends up with an ugly HTTP 500 error page. Although you can define custom error pages in `web.xml` which should be displayed for certain status codes or exception types only, there's no way that you can get it nicely in a `FacesMessage` which you at end can display in a `h:message`.

The only way to do this all nicely is to allow unlimited sized uploads or a 1GB limit or so (which may be a pain, but after all, it's just the client's own decision to do so ;) .. to avoid complaining clients, ensure that there's a **clear** message somewhere at the form about maximum allowed sizes). This way you can take benefit of a real `Validator` which will display the `ValidatorException` in the associated `h:message`, e.g:

```
private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB

public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (((UploadedFile) value).getSize() > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Sorry, max 10MB allowed."));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to upload a file greater than the values configured in web.xml with uploadMaxFileSize and uploadMaxSize params. The problem is that I am waiting a SizeLimitExceededException, but this exception is never thrown. The page reloads and I dont see any error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like Balus C said, it's a well known issue. See: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1381

I think a later version of Tomahwak fixes this.